# Split list into two parts based on some delimiter in each list element in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have a python list

```
my_list = ['owner/NN', 'is/VBZ', 'pleasant/JJ', 'and/CC', 'entertaining/JJ', './.']
```

I want to split it into two parts (based on delimeter '/' presented in each list element), so that I can get two seperate list

```
my_list_1 = ['owner', 'is', 'pleasant', 'and', 'entertaining', '.']
my_list_2 = ['NN', 'VBZ', 'JJ', 'CC', 'JJ', '.']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
split_items = (i.split('/') for i in my_list)
my_list1, my_list2 = zip(*split_items)
```

This creates 2 tuples. If you really need lists, you can convert them by

```
my_list1, my_list2 = map(list, (my_list1, my_list2))
```

Comment: Much more pythonic than the other answers, very nice!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but  instead of using zip and map I would prefer to use numpy like  
split_items = np.array[i.split('/') for i in my_list] and then my_list_1 = split_items[:,0] and my_list_2 = split_items[:,1]

Comment: isn't that what this code does? The `map` part is only needed if you really need `list` instead of `tuple`, and can also be expressed as `my_list1, my_list2 = list(my_list1), list(my_list2)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` to split on delimiter:

```
my_list = ['owner/NN', 'is/VBZ', 'pleasant/JJ', 'and/CC', 'entertaining/JJ', './.']

lst1, lst2 = [], []
for x in my_list:
    part1, part2 = x.split('/')
    lst1.append(part1)
    lst2.append(part2)
```

Or using list comprehensions:

```
lst1, lst2 = [x.split('/')[0] for x in my_list], [x.split('/')[1] for x in my_list]
```

Comment: why not use tuple unpacking? `part1, part2 = x.split('/'); lst1.append(part1);...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop and `split`:

```
my_list = ['owner/NN', 'is/VBZ', 'pleasant/JJ', 'and/CC', 'entertaining/JJ', './.']

my_list1 = []
my_list2 = []
for el in my_list:
     my_list1.append(el.split("/")[0])
     my_list2.append(el.split("/")[1])


>>> my_list1
['owner', 'is', 'pleasant', 'and', 'entertaining', '.']
>>> my_list2
['NN', 'VBZ', 'JJ', 'CC', 'JJ', '.']
```

Comment: Would store el.split("/") in a variable rather than calling it twice. Should be a bit faster

Comment: If the string to split are very long, yes that may help. But for that short strings, It shouldn't speed up very much the computation I think :)

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
my_list = ['owner/NN', 'is/VBZ', 'pleasant/JJ', 'and/CC', 'entertaining/JJ', './.']
my_list_1 = []
my_list_2 = []
delim = '/'
for item in my_list:
    parts = item.split(delim)
    my_list_1.append(parts[0])
    my_list_2.append(parts[1])
```